# simple xml ui for android device

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am new in Android. I need to create a simple UI like on image below:

[image]

On background (now it red) I need image that will have to stretch for screen. Above the background image I need EditText and Button as on the figure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I understand you are new to Android. There are many tutorials for beginners in Android development for a headstart that you can google. But, anyway, to help you answer your question, here's what you should be putting in your xml:

> main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText android:id="@+id/editText"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, on your `Activity`, call `setContentView(R.layout.main)` on the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: i think this my question is a very broad question, but any case thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative layout with linear layout above it.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/background"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:scaleType="[what ever fits you]"
          [image source and other parameters] />

   <RelativeLayout a
          android:id="@+id/textAndButton" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
          android:orientation="vertical"/>
          <EditText...>
          <Button...>
```

Comment: i think this my question is a very broad question, but any case thanks for answer!